# how to edit and run python3 scripts with Vim plugin pymode in windows 7

Tags: python, vim, scipy

I want to edit and run python3 files with the pymode Vim plugin in windows 7. The official Vim does not support python3 and I download a prebuilt binary version which support python3. It works well with the official python 3.5. However, with that version of python, I failed to install scipy. The output is as follows.

```
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:633: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1542: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1553: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1556: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xlchen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-69hqu9mo\scipy\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\xlchen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-69hqu9mo\scipy\setup.py", line 262, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\xlchen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-69hqu9mo\scipy\setup.py", line 182, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
```

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use a packed distribution which I choose WinPython. It contains scipy and works well too. But if I set the Vim pymode python interpreter to this version of python, Vim crashed when open python file.

Currently, I set the Vim pymode plugin to use the official python so that I can edit python file with Vim but can not run it because the scipy package is missing. I have to open WinPython to run the python script which could not be used in Vim.

I have tried to let the official version python to use the site-pacakge dir of WinPython but still get a failure.

Comment: With what error does vim crash if you set the python interpreter to winpython?

Comment: No error information can be obtained. It just crash.

Answer (score 0):

as a clueless experiment, maybe try this:

- launch the script "scripts\make_winpython_fix.bat" of your Winpython,
- retry your vim opening experience

If it doesn't work, "scripts\make_winpython_movable.bat" put you back in initial state.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by running the script "register_python.bat" under the scripts directory of WinPython root dir.